# SQL Server : create a trigger on update of "current" table to "history" table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers

I'm working on migrating from an Oracle 9i db to SQL Server and trying to work out and translate the one trigger we have to maintain a history of records.  The `History` table has its own `ID` column and all other columns are the same as in the `Current` table.

Here is my trigger as is from the OraDb: (in the OraDb we are using a sequence to increment the "History" PK)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "RC_CURRENT_T" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON RC_CURRENT 
FOR EACH ROW 

  DECLARE var_date VARCHAR2(30 BYTE);
  BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN
      var_date:=TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
      INSERT
      INTO RC_HISTORY
        (
          "ID" ,
          REC_ID ,
          STATUS_DESCR ,
          REQBY_FULLNAME ,
          REQBY_USERNAME ,
          REQBY_EMAIL ,
          REQBY_EMPLID ,
          PCARD_TYPE ,
          BUS_SGMT_DESCR ,
          REQ_TYPE ,
          REQ_CHNGAUTHBY ,
          OP_CNTR_NAME ,
          CARDHOLDER_NAME ,
          CUSTODIAN_NAME ,
          ED_ROLLUP_NUM ,
          CARDHOLDER_ADDRESS ,
          CARDHOLDER_CITY ,
          CARDHOLDER_STATE ,
          CARDHOLDER_ZIP ,
          CARD_NUMBER ,
          GL_CODE ,
          GL_LOCATION ,
          GL_DEPARTMENT ,
          GL_ACCOUNT ,
          GL_SVCSCODE ,
          MONTH_LIMIT ,
          LIMIT_RESTRICTIONS ,
          CARD_LIMIT ,
          REASON_COMMENTS ,
          CREATE_DATE ,
          APPROVER1_NAME ,
          APPROVER1_USERNAME ,
          APPROVER1_EMAIL ,
          APPROVER1_EMPLID ,
          APPROVER1_DATE ,
          APPROVER2_NAME ,
          APPROVER2_USERNAME ,
          APPROVER2_EMAIL ,
          APPROVER2_EMPLID ,
          APPROVER2_DATE ,
          ADMIN_LVL1 ,
          ADMIN_LVL2 ,
          ADMIN_LVL3 ,
          ADMIN_LVL4 ,
          ADMIN_LVL5 ,
          ADMIN_LVL6 ,
          KEYED_DATE ,
          KEYED_BY_NAME ,
          KEYER_CHANGE_TYPE ,
          KEYER_COMMENTS ,
          CARD_STATUS ,
          KEYER_USERNAME ,
          KEYER_EMPLID ,
          USER_FULLNAME,
          OPER_STREET,
          OPER_CITY,
          OPER_STATE,
          OPER_ZIP,
          USER_PHONE,
          USER_EMAIL,
          USER_HYCHY_SETUP,
          USER_ASSIGNED_USERID,
          USER_PROCESS_DATE,
          USER_DISTRIBUTION,
          USER_REQUESTTYPE,
          REC_ENTRY_DATE
        )
        VALUES
        (
          RC_HISTORY_SEQ.nextval ,
          :OLD.REC_ID ,
          :OLD.STATUS_DESCR ,
          :OLD.REQBY_FULLNAME ,
          :OLD.REQBY_USERNAME ,
          :OLD.REQBY_EMAIL ,
          :OLD.REQBY_EMPLID ,
          :OLD.PCARD_TYPE ,
          :OLD.BUS_SGMT_DESCR ,
          :OLD.REQ_TYPE ,
          :OLD.REQ_CHNGAUTHBY ,
          :OLD.OP_CNTR_NAME ,
          :OLD.CARDHOLDER_NAME ,
          :OLD.CUSTODIAN_NAME ,
          :OLD.ED_ROLLUP_NUM ,
          :OLD.CARDHOLDER_ADDRESS ,
          :OLD.CARDHOLDER_CITY ,
          :OLD.CARDHOLDER_STATE ,
          :OLD.CARDHOLDER_ZIP ,
          :OLD.CARD_NUMBER ,
          :OLD.GL_CODE ,
          :OLD.GL_LOCATION ,
          :OLD.GL_DEPARTMENT ,
          :OLD.GL_ACCOUNT ,
          :OLD.GL_SVCSCODE ,
          :OLD.MONTH_LIMIT ,
          :OLD.LIMIT_RESTRICTIONS ,
          :OLD.CARD_LIMIT ,
          :OLD.REASON_COMMENTS ,
          :OLD.CREATE_DATE ,
          :OLD.APPROVER1_NAME ,
          :OLD.APPROVER1_USERNAME ,
          :OLD.APPROVER1_EMAIL ,
          :OLD.APPROVER1_EMPLID ,
          :OLD.APPROVER1_DATE ,
          :OLD.APPROVER2_NAME ,
          :OLD.APPROVER2_USERNAME ,
          :OLD.APPROVER2_EMAIL ,
          :OLD.APPROVER2_EMPLID ,
          :OLD.APPROVER2_DATE ,
          :OLD.ADMIN_LVL1 ,
          :OLD.ADMIN_LVL2 ,
          :OLD.ADMIN_LVL3 ,
          :OLD.ADMIN_LVL4 ,
          :OLD.ADMIN_LVL5 ,
          :OLD.ADMIN_LVL6 ,
          :OLD.KEYED_DATE ,
          :OLD.KEYED_BY_NAME ,
          :OLD.KEYER_CHANGE_TYPE ,
          :OLD.KEYER_COMMENTS ,
          :OLD.CARD_STATUS ,
          :OLD.KEYER_USERNAME ,
          :OLD.KEYER_EMPLID ,
          :OLD.USER_FULLNAME,
          :OLD.OPER_STREET,
          :OLD.OPER_CITY,
          :OLD.OPER_STATE,
          :OLD.OPER_ZIP,
          :OLD.USER_PHONE,
          :OLD.USER_EMAIL,
          :OLD.USER_HYCHY_SETUP,
          :OLD.USER_ASSIGNED_USERID,
          :OLD.USER_PROCESS_DATE,
          :OLD.USER_DISTRIBUTION,
          :OLD.USER_REQUESTTYPE,
          var_date
        ) ;
    END IF;
  END;
```

I have attempted the follow but get the error message

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT 
>   columns.

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER RC_CURRENT_T 
ON [dbo].[RC_CURRENT] 
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[RC_HISTORY]
    ([REC_ID]
    ,[STATUS_DESCR]
    ,[REQBY_FULLNAME]
    ,[REQBY_USERNAME]
    ,[REQBY_EMAIL]
    ,[REQBY_EMPLID]
    ,[PCARD_TYPE]
    ,[BUS_SGMT_DESCR]
    ,[REQ_TYPE]
    ,[REQ_CHNGAUTHBY]
    ,[OP_CNTR_NAME]
    ,[CARDHOLDER_NAME]
    ,[CUSTODIAN_NAME]
    ,[ED_ROLLUP_NUM]
    ,[CARDHOLDER_ADDRESS]
    ,[CARDHOLDER_CITY]
    ,[CARDHOLDER_STATE]
    ,[CARDHOLDER_ZIP]
    ,[CARD_NUMBER]
    ,[GL_CODE]
    ,[GL_LOCATION]
    ,[GL_DEPARTMENT]
    ,[GL_ACCOUNT]
    ,[GL_SVCSCODE]
    ,[MONTH_LIMIT]
    ,[LIMIT_RESTRICTIONS]
    ,[CARD_LIMIT]
    ,[REASON_COMMENTS]
    ,[CREATE_DATE]
    ,[APPROVER1_NAME]
    ,[APPROVER1_USERNAME]
    ,[APPROVER1_EMAIL]
    ,[APPROVER1_EMPLID]
    ,[APPROVER1_DATE]
    ,[APPROVER2_NAME]
    ,[APPROVER2_USERNAME]
    ,[APPROVER2_EMAIL]
    ,[APPROVER2_EMPLID]
    ,[APPROVER2_DATE]
    ,[ADMIN_LVL1]
    ,[ADMIN_LVL2]
    ,[ADMIN_LVL3]
    ,[ADMIN_LVL4]
    ,[ADMIN_LVL5]
    ,[ADMIN_LVL6]
    ,[KEYED_DATE]
    ,[KEYED_BY_NAME]
    ,[KEYER_CHANGE_TYPE]
    ,[KEYER_COMMENTS]
    ,[CARD_STATUS]
    ,[KEYER_USERNAME]
    ,[KEYER_EMPLID]
    ,[USER_FULLNAME]
    ,[OPER_STREET]
    ,[OPER_CITY]
    ,[OPER_STATE]
    ,[OPER_ZIP]
    ,[USER_PHONE]
    ,[USER_EMAIL]
    ,[USER_HYCHY_SETUP]
    ,[USER_ASSIGNED_USERID]
    ,[USER_PROCESS_DATE]
    ,[USER_DISTRIBUTION]
    ,[USER_REQUESTTYPE]
    ,[REC_ENTRY_DATE]
    )
    SELECT * FROM RC_CURRENT
END
GO
```

I need to maintain the separate ID in the history table for reporting purposes.

Any assistance is very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try to explicity specify the columns for the select? Also, your select must read from 'updated' table (that is the updated record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the old trigger (and the error message)`RC_HISTORY` has 1 extra field compared to `RC_CURRENT` so you have two options.

1. If `[REC_ID]` is an identity column with auto increment you can simply remove it from the list of columns to be inserted to

   ```
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[RC_HISTORY]
   ([STATUS_DESCR]
   ,[REQBY_FULLNAME]
   ,[REQBY_USERNAME]
   ...
   ```
2. If `[REC_ID]` is not set to auto increment then you will have to provide a value to insert into the column

   ```
   SELECT (SELECT MAX([REC_ID])+1 FROM RC_HISTORY), * FROM RC_CURRENT
   ```

I would suggest you try the first option and set the column to be an identity column if it isn't already, I also suggest you also use named columns instead of * for the select values.

Comment: In addtion the the other comments, I'd strongly urge you to NOT store a date as a varchar.  Both oracle and sql server have appropriate data types to store dates.  Storing data as the wrong data type is a recipe for continuing headaches, if not downright disaster.  It is a fundamental design flaw in any rdbms.

Comment: Thank you benni_mac_b and EdStevens.  I went ahead and typed out each column explicitly. The REC_ID(key) is the ID column for the "Current" table but the "History" table has its own ID(key) column and REC_ID has a Current(one)->History(many) relationship on the REC_ID.